# Why isn't the loginButton centered horizontally?

Tags: html, css

My code is:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background-image: url("images/indexBg.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
#container {
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 50px;
  background-color: #cccfe8;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
#login {
  width: 20%;
  height: 15%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #cccfe8;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
#login label {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100px;
}
#loginButton {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
.inp {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
#login>p {
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="login">
  <h1>Login</h1>
  <p>
    <div class="inp">
      <label for="uid">Username :</label>
      <input type="text" id="uid">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="inp">
      <label for="pass">Password :</label>
      <input type="password" id="pass">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="loginButton" class="inp">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In">
    </div>
  </p>
</div>
```

Why isn't the loginButton centered Horizontally, even though the margin is set to auto?

What do I need to do to fix it?

Also, is there a way to center all the elements(including both the inner divs) horizontally? What is the best way to tackle this problem?

Comment: It's 2016, start learning `flexbox` 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
login {
    width: 20%;
    height: 25%; // make it 25% from 15%. 
    text-align: center; //add this tag to your css code.hope it will help you.
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;

    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #cccfe8;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `input` inside of `#loginButton` it is not centered (and I'm assuming is what you're trying to center).

```
#loginButton {
   text-align:center;
}
```

To be frank, there's a lot of not so great practices going on with your CSS. `position: absolute` does not appear to be required (and thus, none of the `top`,`left`,`bottom`,`right` properties either). I also don't know why you are specifying a width and height on `#login`, nor am I entirely sure why you have a `padding-right` on `#login label` if you desire to have everything centered in `#login`.

Vastly simplifying the code, it could look like this:

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    background-image: url("images/indexBg.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#container {
    padding: 50px;
    margin: 50px;
    background-color: #cccfe8;
    opacity: 0.9;
}

#login {
    text-align:center;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #cccfe8;
    opacity: 0.9;
}

#login label {
  text-align:right;
  display:inline-block;
}

#loginButton {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
    <div id="login">
        <h1>Login</h1>
            <div class="inp">
                <label for="uid">Username : </label>
                <input type="text" id="uid">
            </div> <br>
            <div class="inp">
                <label for="pass">Password : </label>
                <input type="password" id="pass">   
            </div> <br>
            <div id="loginButton" class="inp">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In">
            </div>
    </div>
```

Also, if you want to have the field labels above their inputs, just change `#login label` to be `{ display:block; }` and remove the `text-align:right`

Answer (score 2):

Please add style of #loginButton in css :

```
 text-align:center;
```

Or
     width:50px;

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

for horizontal alignment try

```
<div id="wrapper" style="text-align: center">    
    <div id="yourdiv" style="display: inline-block;">You text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your #login id have height:15%. Don't use any height in the id, if you added any additional textbox or any property it will affect the height.

In any case if you specified the height the box will appear in the particular height only, so you may add some increase the height of the box.

change the code:

```
#login {
width: 20%;
height: 30%;
text-align:center;
}
```